# django to return json format data to prototype ajax

Tags: django, django-templates

is there a way i can pass json format data through django HttpResponse. I am trying to call the view through prototype ajax and return json format data.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do something like this inside your app views.py

```
    import json

    def ajax_handler(req, your_parameter):

        json_response = json.dumps(convert_data_to_json)

        return HttpResponse(json_response,mimetype='application/json')
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on Lombo's answer, you might want to utilize the [`request.is_ajax()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) method. This checks the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header is XmlHttpRequest.

This is a good way to avoid sending a json response to a regular GET - which I guess at worst is just confusing to your users, but also lets you use the same view for ajax vs. non-ajax requests. This approach makes it easier to build apps that [degrade gracefully](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

For example:

```
def your_view(request):
    data_dict = # get some data

    if request.is_ajax():
        # return json data for ajax request
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data_dict),mimetype='application/json')

    # return a new page otherwise
    return render_to_response("your_template.html", data_dict)
```

This approach works particularly well for form processing also.